# internal IP asssigned to ESXi external vSwitch issue

Tags: networking, esxi

On my esxi I have 2 NIC's one for internal connection another for external connections. I have a VM machine on internal ip something like 192.123.... connected to local network. If I would attach a second network card on my VM and giving a second internal ip (192.123...) and on vSwitch attaching to external NIC,  could I access internet on this machine?
I need a solution to get internet on my backend server and every feedback would be welcome.

vSwitch has external and internal NIC's

```
##NIC internal
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static

           address 192.168.123.228
           netmask 255.255.255.0
           network 192.168.123.0
           gateway 192.168.123.1
           dsn-nameservers 192.168.123.1

## NIC that would access internet 
auth eth1 
iface eth1 inet static 

           address 192.168.123.229
           netmask 255.255.255.0
```